# pentaho error and crash

Tags: java, database, servlets, pentaho

I use Pentaho 5.0 and i am getting the following error please help me.
thank you

> 2015-01-21 09:08:59,724 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.sql.SQLLookupRule] Error Start:
>   Pentaho Pentaho Platform Core 5.0.1-stable.-1 2015-01-21 09:08:59,724
>   ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.sql.SQLLookupRule]
>   c0981df6-a144-11e4-b098-d4ae52d4a4b4:COMPONENT:context-301995187-1421827738915:global-department-list.xactionConnectFactory.ERROR_0001 - Database connection could not be established to: SampleData org.pentaho.platform.api.data.DBDatasourceServiceException:
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name SampleData is not bound in
>   this Context  at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.BaseDatasourceService.getJndiDataSource(BaseDatasourceService.java:113)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledOrJndiDatasourceService.retrieve(PooledOrJndiDatasourceService.java:50)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledOrJndiDatasourceService.getDataSource(PooledOrJndiDatasourceService.java:110)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.connections.sql.SQLConnection.initWithJNDI(SQLConnection.java:192)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.connections.sql.SQLConnection.setProperties(SQLConnection.java:106)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.PentahoConnectionFactory.getConnection(PentahoConnectionFactory.java:129)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.PentahoConnectionFactory.getConnection(PentahoConnectionFactory.java:73)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.sql.SQLBaseComponent.getConnection(SQLBaseComponent.java:893)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.sql.SQLBaseComponent.getConnection(SQLBaseComponent.java:859)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.sql.SQLBaseComponent.getDatasourceConnection(SQLBaseComponent.java:809)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.sql.SQLBaseComponent.executeAction(SQLBaseComponent.java:211)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.ComponentBase.execute(ComponentBase.java:465)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeComponent(RuntimeContext.java:1313)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeAction(RuntimeContext.java:1279)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.performActions(RuntimeContext.java:1176)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeLoop(RuntimeContext.java:1122)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:910)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.executeInternal(SolutionEngine.java:386)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:305)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:184)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.globalStartup(PentahoSystem.java:868)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:825)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:822)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.security.SecurityHelper.runAsSystem(SecurityHelper.java:333)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.globalStartup(PentahoSystem.java:822)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:282)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:182)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) Caused
>   by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name SampleData is not bound
>   in this Context   at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)    at
>   org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)    at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)   at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.BaseDatasourceService.getJndiDataSource(BaseDatasourceService.java:73)
>     ... 52 more 2015-01-21 09:08:59,727 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.sql.SQLLookupRule] Error end:
>   2015-01-21 09:08:59,727 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.sql.SQLLookupRule]
>   c0981df6-a144-11e4-b098-d4ae52d4a4b4:COMPONENT:context-301995187-1421827738915:global-department-list.xactionSQLBaseComponent.ERROR_0007
>   - Connection to data source is not valid 2015-01-21 09:08:59,728 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine]
>   c0981df6-a144-11e4-b098-d4ae52d4a4b4:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/Secure/global-department-list.xaction:
>   Action Sequence execution failed, see details below | Error Time:
>   Wednesday, January 21, 2015 9:08:59 AM CET | Session ID: admin |
>   Instance Id: c0981df6-a144-11e4-b098-d4ae52d4a4b4 | Action Sequence:
>   global-department-list.xaction | Execution Stack: EXECUTING ACTION:
>   Query For Departments (SQLLookupRule) | Action Class: SQLLookupRule |
>   Action Desc: Query For Departments | Loop Index: 0 Stack
>   Trace:org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ActionExecutionException:
>   RuntimeContext.ERROR_0017 - Action failed to execute  at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeComponent(RuntimeContext.java:1341)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeAction(RuntimeContext.java:1279)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.performActions(RuntimeContext.java:1176)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeLoop(RuntimeContext.java:1122)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:910)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.executeInternal(SolutionEngine.java:386)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:305)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:184)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.globalStartup(PentahoSystem.java:868)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:825)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:822)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.security.SecurityHelper.runAsSystem(SecurityHelper.java:333)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.globalStartup(PentahoSystem.java:822)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:282)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:182)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>
> 2015-01-21 09:13:41,399 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /jpivot/jpivot/messages_supported_languages.properties not found in
>   plugin jpivot 2015-01-21 09:13:42,799 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_it-IT.properties not found in plugin
>   pentaho-cdf-dd 2015-01-21 09:13:43,049 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties.properties not found in plugin saiku
>   2015-01-21 09:13:43,115 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties_it.properties not found in plugin
>   saiku 2015-01-21 09:13:43,224 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties_it-IT.properties not found in plugin
>   saiku 2015-01-21 09:15:43,191 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_it-IT.properties not found in plugin
>   pentaho-cdf-dd 2015-01-21 09:15:43,470 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties.properties not found in plugin saiku
>   2015-01-21 09:15:43,536 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties_it.properties not found in plugin
>   saiku 2015-01-21 09:15:43,603 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties_it-IT.properties not found in plugin
>   saiku 2015-01-21 09:28:22,749 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties.properties not found in plugin saiku
>   2015-01-21 09:28:22,816 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties_it.properties not found in plugin
>   saiku 2015-01-21 09:43:57,636 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /jpivot/jpivot/messages_supported_languages.properties not found in
>   plugin jpivot 2015-01-21 09:44:00,018 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties.properties not found in plugin saiku
>   2015-01-21 09:44:00,079 ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]
>   GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource
>   /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties_it.properties not found in plugin
>   saiku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log, i got to see this error : `Database connection could not be established to: SampleData`. It seems that you have entered a wrong database credentials where the xaction is trying to query ( `global-department-list.xaction` *to be precise*).

Please check the database credentials properly in your xaction.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you for your replay, but the simpledata is an old db, I don't know because there is this connection.

Comment: every time it crash there is this error: - Resource /jpivot/jpivot/messages_supported_languages.properties not found in plugin jpivot
 - Resource /BTable/resources/lang/messages_en.properties not found in plugin BTable
 - Resource /BTable/resources/lang/messages_en_US.properties not found in plugin BTable
 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_en.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_en_US.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
 - Resource /saiku-ui/saikuplugin.properties.properties not found in plugin saiku

Comment: Sampledata is an inbuilt hypersonic database in pentaho... As i said earlier u need to check ur xaction on the db connectivity. Also recheck on thr plugin installation of saiku.. But first check on the flow of the xaction sequences